# MS Access 2010 Issue

Tags: ms-access

Table1            feildes
Product{ID,Product,Quantity(in peices),Cost(per peice)}

table2

Customer{ID, Name, Type(local,sale's man)}

table 3

customer order{ID, date,customer*, product*,quntity,price}
here customer is coming from table 2 named as customer while product is coming from table1 named as products

i just want to show remaining items in order table. any can help me to make this happen?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBVdQ.png)

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Add sample data and desired results and the current query you are using.

Comment: You have CustomerID joined to Product in your query. That's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to know how much of each product remains after filling orders? This is calculating inventory balance - a common topic. You need a table that records receipt of product, which is apparently your Products table but I think would be better titled ProductReceived. Do an aggregate query on ProductReceived and an aggregate query on Orders then do another query that joins the two and subtracts the latter from the former. Customer table not needed for this. Products table would just be a lookup table for product info - no Quantity or Cost fields as these belong in ProductReceived. Products table should have the selling price you want to charge.

You have misspelled 'piece' in your field names.

Advise no spaces, punctuation, or special characters in field names (underscore is only exception). Better would be Qty_Pieces.